# How to customize will_pagination?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I am using will_pagination with ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.8 and getting pagination link like,

```
      << previous  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ... 66 67 next >> and 
      << previous 1 2 ... 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 ... 66 67 next >>
```

Help me how to present pagination link like below,

```
      << previous 1 2 3 4 5 ... 66 67 next >> (or)
      << previous 1 2 ... 30 31 ... 66 67 next >>
```

Want to customize page links, here i like bring gap css after page 5 instead of page 9. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own `LinkRenderer` and pass it as the `renderer` option:

```
will_paginate(@items, :renderer => My:LinkRenderer)
```

Have a look at [LinkRendererBase](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/master/lib/will_paginate/view_helpers/link_renderer_base.rb) and [LinkRenderer](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/master/lib/will_paginate/view_helpers/link_renderer.rb) to see how the default renderer works.

**Update:** Actually you don't need to create your own renderer to achieve what you want. Customize WillPaginate like:

```
WillPaginate::ViewHelpers.pagination_options[:inner_window] = 2
WillPaginate::ViewHelpers.pagination_options[:outer_window] = 1
```

And it will render the pagination bar like the way you want it to. You can add the initialization to an initializer file in the `config/initializers` folder.

Comment: Hi Thanks, I have added the pagination_list_link_renderer.rb file under lib/ folder and I changed in view page <%= will_paginate(@results, :renderer =>PaginationListLinkRenderer ,:inner_window=>2,:outer_window=>2, :params=>{"search"=> params[:search]}) %>. But stil not get any changes. can you please help me?

Comment: Thank you! its bring pagination like << 1 2 ... 3 4 5 ... 66 67 >> when I gave :outer_window=>1 and :inner_window=>1 in initializer file.